# Change the srcset image onhover when ready (image loaded) in picture tag

Tags: javascript, image, onload, readystate, avif

I have a site with loads of images. At first I show them in low quality to save bandwidth for the visitor. If you hover over an image the image should be replaced by a high-quality image of the same size. My site runs without jQuery.

I tried `onmouseover` on both the `srcset` tag and the `img` tag, but this does only work on the `img` tag if the browser has no `avif` support:

```html
<picture>
  <source onmouseover="this.srcset='test.avif'"  loading="lazy" data-srcset="lq.avif" type="image/avif" srcset="lq.avif">
  <img onmouseover="this.src='test.jpg'" loading="lazy" src="lq.jpg`" data-src="lq.jpg">
</picture>
```

How do I prevent the image from changing immediately and showing an empty frame while loading the hq image?

Comment: did you try to load the image from JS? I mean by having `new Image()` and `.onload(...)` and setting the HQ image src after loading, of course you need to make it looks like a white frame before loading to have the result you need

Comment: That is a bit defeating the purpose of srcset isn't it?